# How to add notification in the beginning of each month in android

Tags: android, calendar, android-notifications, android-calendar

Hi I built an application - and I try to add notification that appear in the 1st of each month.
How can I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create a service that periodically checks the date and creates the notification on the first of the month.

Information about Services:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Information about Notifications:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html